# django2 views.pyl: attribute the values from list

Tags: python, django

Beginner of Django. Several questions about Django

Q: How to write a proper way to let Django views.py read values individually from list without ‘’

Example:
Urls.py

```
path('booklist/<str:pk>/', views.Paristour, name='Paristour'),
```

views.py

it works with single value

```
def Paristour(request,pk):
    a =('aa')
    if a == pk:
       contact = "good"
     else:
       return render(request, '404.html', locals())

    return render(request, 'paristour.html', locals())
```

It doesn’t work. All I want is to pk == aa, 
pk == bb, pk ==cc
without aa, bb, or cc, the rest of str(string) goes to 404 html

```
def Paristour(request,pk):
a =['aa', 'bb', 'cc']

if a == pk:
    contact = "good"
else:
    return render(request, '404.html', locals())

return render(request, 'paristour.html', locals())
```

best regards

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain a little more i'm sort of confused.
Assuming you want to check if pk is present in the list you can just use `if pk in a:`
Assuming you want to pk to be equal to a, b and c, you can use `if pk=set(a)[0] and len(set(a)) == 1:`

Comment: sorry about my poor description. The solution that you wrote "if pk in a" is exactly what I want to be. Big Thanx!!!! really appreciated!